# Node.js / Koa: wait for API call before response

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, koa

I have only basic JS knowledge (mainly jQuery), so this might be a really simple one.
And do realise performance-wise it might not be the best solution, but for now this is just proof of concept.

I have this simple Koa app. All I'm trying to do is to call an external API (Airtable) when the /callapi route is accessed and add some data from the API response to ctx.body.

However, I get a 404 Not Found when going to http://localhost:3000/callapi
I understand this is probably because the API call is asynchronous, so Node.js / Koa don't wait for it to finish and continue the execution, but there is no code setting the response body elsewhere, so it results in 404.

How can I achieve that?
Happy to use other routing middleware or additional middleware if needed.

I believe the Promises with async/await is the new way to go, which Koa embraces, so if I can somehow add / wrap this, it would be the best I guess.

```
const KoaRoute = require('koa-route');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'keyI6rZxwsXXXXXXX'}).base('appXXXXXX');


app.use(KoaRoute.get('/callapi', async function (ctx) {
    await base('Couples').find('reclnxjiMeSljrzP0', function(err, record) {
        console.log('Retrieved', record.id);
        ctx.body = "Record ID from API: " + record.id;
    });
}));


app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: Why are you hitting /testapi when the route you have declared says /callapi?

Comment: @Waldemar, please use `async` like this - ```async ctx => await your_api();```

Comment: @CoryRobinson sorry, it was a typo. Edited.

Comment: @AllenHaley I edited the code above trying await / async, but still no luck. I'm probably not getting the whole await / async syntax right. Would be great if you can edit the whole block of relevant code ...really struggling with this one.

The API call itself works fine - the console.log('Retrieved', record.id); displays a valid piece of info coming from the API.

Comment: @Waldemar, I added answer but am not sure what the return value is. Please check return value if it returns only record or other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `await` is wrong. Please try this.

```
...
app.use(KoaRoute.get('/callapi', async function (ctx) {
    /* please check return value if it returns correct value. */
    try {
        const record = await getBase();
        console.log('Retrieved', record.id);
        ctx.body = "Record ID from API: " + record.id;
    } catch (err) {
        // handle exception
    }
}));
...
```

EDITED: Please add the following function and try again above thing.

```
function getBase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        base('Couples').find('reclnxjiMeSljrzP0', function(err, record) {
            console.log('Retrieved', record.id);
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(record);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The base(...).find(...) method does not return the record from the API unfortunately. Maybe there is a way to "wrap" the base(...).find(...) call into something to make the execution first wait for it to finish? As in to make it await/sync compatible so to say?

Comment: @Waldemar, I updated the answer by adding another function which gets `bases` asynchronously.